# ASP.Net get count of amount of files selected for upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am letting users upload multiple files via the `<input type="file" name="MTNLocationFileUpload" multiple="multiple" />` in my ASP.net MVC application and am trying to figure out how to get a count of how many files where selected. I tried using `Request.Files.Count` but that always returns `1`. What is the correct call to figure out how many files where selected?

C# Code:
[Route("MTNLocationFileUpload", Name = "Upload Mountain Location Files"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult MTNLocationFilesUpload()
{
var fileCount = Request.Files.Count;

```
    if (fileCount > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileRoot"] + @"MTNLocations\" + Request["Location"] + @"\");
                var d = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
                {
                    var newFile = new FileData()
                    {
                        FileLocation = path,
                        FileName = fileName
                    };

                    db.FileData.Add(newFile);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    var newLocationFile = new MTNAlarmLocationFile()
                    {
                        FileID = newFile.ID,
                        LocationID = int.Parse(Request["ID"]),
                    };

                    db.MTNAlarmLocationFiles.Add(newLocationFile);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("MTNAlarmDetail", new { locationID = Request["ID"] });
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form class="inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="MTNLocationFileUpload">
    <span style="font-weight: bold"> Files</span>
    <br />

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Location)
    <input type="file" name="MTNLocationFileUpload" multiple="multiple" /><input class="inline" type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
</form>
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your issue. `Request.Files.Count` returns 1 when zero or one file is selected and I submit the form. If I select multiple files and submit the form, I get the correct count from `Request.Files.Count`

Answer (score 1):

`Request.Files.Count` should give you the number of files you selected. (*Copied and pasted your code and verified it. Worked for me (tested in chrome browser*))

Another approach is to use a collection of `HttpPostedFileBase` as the parameter of your action method and use the `Count` method ?

The name of the parameter should match with your input file control's `name` attribute value.

```
[Route("MTNLocationFileUpload", Name = "Upload Mountain Location Files"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult MTNLocationFilesUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>
                                                                      MTNLocationFileUpload)
{
  var fileCount = MTNLocationFileUpload.Count();
  foreach(var file in MTNLocationFileUpload)
  {
    // to do :Continue uploading
  }
  // to do : Return something
}
```